# Does Postgresql support Oracle's UTF-16?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, oracle12c, azure-postgresql

I am working on migration of oracle-12c with utf16 to azure postgresql database.

While creating database in azure portal, I have to provide a collation name. Can someone please suggest with compatible (oracle utf16) collation name.

Comment: Neither UTF8 nor UTF16 is a collation, those are character _encodings_. Postgres supports UTF8 which is compatible with UTF16.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 and UTF-16 are *encodings* (“character sets” in Oracle lingo): they determine which number represents what character. PostgreSQL supports and recommends UTF-8, but does not support UTF-16, since it only supports encodings that extend ASCII.

Choose the `UTF8` encoding and let Oracle do the conversion.

A *collation* determines the sorting order of character strings. You should choose a collation that is similar to the one you are using in Oracle, so that the result of an `ORDER BY` will be similar.